# Find the principal argument of $1+\cos\frac{11\pi}{9} + i\sin\frac{11\pi}{9}$

Tags: complex-numbers

If I write 1 as $\cos 0 + i\sin 0$

The expression becomes 
$$2\cos\frac{11\pi}{18} \left(\cos\frac{11\pi}{18}+i\sin\frac{11\pi}{18}\right)$$
The argument can be separated.
 So the argument for first part will be $-\pi$, or rather should be, because I am confused about the coming steps. What should I do next?

Comment: When $|z|=1$ the principal argument of $1+z$ is half that of $z$.  That's my story and I'm sticking with it.

Comment: You've already got the argument: $\frac{11\pi}{18}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluate first,

$$\frac{\sin\frac{11\pi}{9}}{1+\cos\frac{11\pi}{9}}
=\frac{2\sin\frac{11\pi}{18}\cos\frac{11\pi}{18}}{2\cos^2\frac{11\pi}{18}}
=\frac{\sin\frac{11\pi}{18}}{\cos\frac{11\pi}{18}}=\tan\frac{11\pi}{18}$$

So, since $\sin\frac{11\pi}{9}$ is negative, i.e. the 4th quadrant, the principal argument is $\frac{11\pi}{18}-\pi = -\frac{7\pi}{18} $

Or, continue with your expression to get the same result,

$$2\cos\frac{11\pi}{18} \left(\cos\frac{11\pi}{18}+i\sin\frac{11\pi}{18}\right)
=2\cos\frac{7\pi}{18}e^{-i\pi}e^{i\frac{11\pi}{18}}
=2\cos\frac{7\pi}{18}e^{-i\frac{7\pi}{18}} $$

Thus, $ -\frac{7\pi}{18}$.

Edit: Maybe it is implicit to some, but as Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc alluded below, the principal argument is defined within $(-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: How did u get the first part of the expression? Also shouldn’t the quadrant it is in have an effect on the sign of the argument?

Comment: For the first part, if $z=a+ib=re^{i\theta}$, $\tan\theta = \frac ba$.

Comment: Can u continue what I did up there? I am sure it can be found using what I did, only it might be a little longer.

Comment: Yeah, I added your approach in the answer.

Comment: The principal value of $Arg Z$ is $-\frac{7 \pi}{18}$. see my answer below.

Comment: overlooked (-pi, pi). appreciate it. will correct

Comment: How about this; what will be the argument of $2\cos\frac{11\pi}{18}$? Cause we can separate the arguments in the product and simply add the arguments

Comment: @Aditya Agree, just revised it to the sum approach

Comment: Then the arg of first part will be $-\pi$ and the arg of the second part will be $\frac{11\pi}{18}$ adding them gives $\frac{-7\pi}{18}$. Is this right?

Comment: @Aditya - yeah, you get the right answer this way. Just make sure you check it indeed fall inside the principal range (-pi,pi)

Answer (score 2):

Let $ O $ be the origin, $ C $ be 1, $ P = 1 + \cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{9}\right) + i \sin \left(\frac{11\pi}{9} \right) $, and $ R $ be 2, all in the complex plane.  Then, if you draw a picture of this, you see that $ O, P, R $ are all points on the circle of radius 1 centered at $ C $. $ \angle RCP $ is $ -\frac{7\pi}{9} $.  By a basic result in geometry on inscribed angles in a circle, $ \angle ROP = \frac{1}{2} \angle RCP = -\frac{7\pi}{18} $.  Here I am using the convention of negative numbers to denote clockwise angles.  I edited this answer because I did not notice the clockwise angles when I looked at this before.

Answer (score 2):

The principal value of Arg lies in $(-\pi,\pi]$ and $e^{2ni\pi}=1, e^{i\pi}=-1.$

Given that $$Z=2 \cos 110^0 ~e^{11i \pi/18}= |2\cos 110^0|~ (1) e^{11i\pi/18} \implies 
Arg Z= \pi+11\pi/18$$ in order to bring this value in $(-\pi, \pi]$ we add $2n\pi$ to it where $n=\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3,...$, Finally, the principal value of $Arg Z$ is
$$\pi+ \frac{11 \pi}{18}-2\pi=- \frac{7 \pi}{18}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos\dfrac{11\pi}{18}=\cos\left(\pi-\dfrac{7\pi}{18}\right)=-\cos\dfrac{7\pi}{18}<0$$

$$\sin\dfrac{11\pi}{18}=\sin\left(\pi-\dfrac{7\pi}{18}\right)=\sin\dfrac{7\pi}{18}>0$$

Using [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation)

the principal argument will be $$\arctan\left(\dfrac{-2\cos\dfrac{7\pi}{18}\sin\dfrac{7\pi}{18}}{2^2\cos\dfrac{7\pi}{18}}\right)=\arctan\left(\tan\left(-\dfrac{7\pi}{18}\right)\right)=-\dfrac{7\pi}{18}$$